# Con JS, producir scroll en un elemento, invocando el evento desde otro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

El contexto bajo el porqué lo quiero realizar es un poco difícil de explicar, pero en resumen quiero crear mi propia función de scroll (invokeScroll), que se añada cono evento de tipo "wheel" a un "contenedor1", y que cause un scroll en un "contenedor2".

- contenedor1: Área donde se debe invocar o realizar el scroll.
- contenedor2: En este caso muy particular, este contenedor esta bloqueado por la propiedad
  CSS de pointer-events: "none", así que ningún evento de mouse tiene efecto en el.

Un ejemplo de como lo estoy realizando (pero no me convence) se encuentra en este [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-euler-thvptr?file=/src/App.js).

Si no gustan verlo en sandbox:

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open sans", sans-serif;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.App > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  text-align: center;
}

.App .scrolleableArea {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const customScroll = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    const scrolleableArea = document.querySelector(".scrolleableArea");
    scrolleableArea.scrollTo({
      top: scrolleableArea.scrollTop + e.deltaY * 3,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollArea = document.querySelector(".scrollArea");
    scrollArea.addEventListener("wheel", customScroll, { passive: false });

    return () => scrollArea.removeEventListener("wheel", customScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="scrolleableArea">
        <div style={{ height: "3000px" }}>
          Area donde se debe producir el scroll
          <br />
          <br />
          (Scroll bloqueado por la propiedad
          <br />
          <strong>pointer-events: "none"</strong>)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="scrollArea">Area donde se debe invocar el scroll</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Como se puede ver en el ejemplo, he logrado causar el efecto, pero se puede percibir un delay o retraso al hacer varios scrolls rápidos y seguidos ¿Cómo podría conseguir un efecto natural y que se haga en tiempo real, o como lo harían ustedes?

Cabe resaltar que este "contenedor1" no tiene una altura suficiente como para tener desplazamiento vertical, por lo que **addEventListener('scroll', invokeScroll)** no se debería usar, ni la propiedad de **scrollTop** del "contenedor1", ya que este al no tener desplazamiento vertical siempre será 0; en su lugar podría servir **addEventListener('wheel', invokeScroll)** que invoca la función sin importar si el "contenedor1" tiene o no desplazamiento vertical.

Comment: Excelente trabajo, hasta donde se puede desplazar el scroll down?, no veo que funcione scrollup

Comment: Asi como esta si llega al final del scroll, ya no sube

Comment: @g.4 mmmm pues acabo de ver nuevamente el ejemplo, y si realiza scroll up.

Comment: podrias intentar usar `scrolleableArea.scrollTo({...` como lo indica en https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle

Comment: Lo dejaré como tú ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este tipo de retraso es causado por diferentes procesamientos que ocurren cuando llamas a la función que produce el desplazamiento, para evitarlo puedes usar una función [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) la cual optimiza el llamado de la funciones como lo dice en la documentación *"Crea una función throttle que solo invoca funct como máximo una vez por cada milisegundos de espera"*, asi que dentro de `useEffect` quedaría algo asi:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollArea = document.querySelector(".scrollArea");
    scrollArea.addEventListener("wheel", customScroll, { passive: false });

    return () => scrollArea.removeEventListener("wheel", customScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="scrolleableArea">
        <div style={{ height: "3000px" }}>
```

Comment: useCallback no se puede invocar dentro del useEffect, luego quitando el hook, tampoco parece funcionar :/

Comment: Lo dejaré como tú ejemplo.